# Unable to SSH into remote machine but able to ping - VPNC

Tags: ssh, remote, ping

I'm writing and posting the solution that I found with a recent issue regarding VScode remote server, ssh and VPNC. Yep, I lost to much time on it, hope to save your time.

**Issue**

I had to change VPN client, using the default ubuntu VPN client cisco-compatible (vpnc).
After setting up the VPN, I was unable to access my remote SSH machine. However, I was able to ping the machine.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging a little bit with `ssh -v ...`, I had this error:

```
expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
```

To fix that [(other link)](https://serverfault.com/a/697350),
In `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` edit the next line:

```
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
MACs hmac-sha1
```

Good. SSH through the terminal should now be working fine.

After that, I tried to open Vscode through the remote machine, but I received the following error:

```
Remote-SSH hangs on "Setting up SSH Host <remote> (details) Initializing VS Code Server"
```

which basically was hanging infinitely, returning Connection timed out after some time.

After looking at every answer and post on this site, I suspected the issue was somehow related to MTU since I was able to look at the terminal and see that the connection was established. Also, I removed `.vscode_server` from the remote machine, thus, I Knew I had to upload the executable from the host to the remote.

To confirm the MTU issue, I run the following command:

`scp file_large user@host`

The result? Copy was stalled as soon as I ran the command. Now, the MTU problem was pretty much confirmed.

**Fix MTU issue**

To test the Maximum MTU size available, I ping the server with the ping command:

```
ping -M do -s 1500 remote_ip
```

lowering the MTU size (in this case 1500) until the command DO NOT return

```
 ping: local error: message too long, mtu=1500
```

After finding the MTU size (mine was 1370), I change the MTU of my VPN tunnel name:

```
sudo ifconfig your_tunnel_name mtu 1370 up
```

and tested that the scp command was running fine. Unfortunately, this command is not permanent, so we have to make it [permanent with](https://serverfault.com/a/716526):

create a file under `/etc/network/if-up.d`

with

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$IFACE" = "your_tunnel_name" ]; then
    sudo ifconfig your_tunnel_name mtu 1300
fi
```

At this time, I was able to access my machine!